# Faking socket.io connection from command line

Tags: javascript, testing, node.js, socket.io

Once you have in place a failry complex socket.io + node.js setup, how could you make some tests without using the browser? Do you know if is it possible to create node.js clients that use socket.io to communicate with the "master" node.js server? (the one to which are talking to the browsers). Of course, the logic in the browser would be copied in those clients, but still...

Comment: I believe latest socket.io can be used from cli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now the official socket.io-client by LearnBoost

npm -g install socket.io-client

I also made some tests using the phantomjs headless browser

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, the `socket.io-client` module isn't usable from node itself but requires some sort of shim.

Comment: socket.io-client is usable from node.